# Avoid 'unbound function' ESLint warning when passing a static method reference to a super constructor in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have a class that has to call its superclass with a function passed as argument. I want to pass a static function from the same class:

```
export abstract class ChildAdapter extends Adapter{

  protected constructor() {
    super(ChildAdapter.index);
  }

  static async index() {...}
```

and I am getting an ESLint warning: *ESLint: Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`.(@typescript-eslint/unbound-method)*.

One option would be to use some kind of external global function here, but I want all methods encapsulated in the class just to keep things together. I can not refactor the code so the call to `super()` does not contain the function reference.

I am confused as to why ESLint warns me about the static function as it has no "this" at all. What can I do to avoid the problems stated in the ESLint warning?

Comment: You could pass `ChildAdapter.index.bind(ChildAdapter)` (...or `() => ChildAdapter.index()` at the expense of a little indirection) instead.

Comment: This warning is telling you something important. `static` methods can use `this`, which is the class itself, and often do, so you must bind them like any other method.

Comment: ...indeed, there's always a `this` and it pays to be aware of it at all times. A worthy read if you're confused: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @spender feel free to make an answer, I''ll accept it :) However, only bind version worked for me, ()=>... made a warning. Real index() function got some parameters and generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to fix this issue:

```
export abstract class ChildAdapter extends Adapter{

  protected constructor() {
    super(ChildAdapter.index.bind(ChildAdapter);
  }

  static async index() {...}
```

or:

```
export abstract class ChildAdapter extends Adapter{

  protected constructor() {
    super(() => ChildAdapter.index());
  }

  static async index() {...}
```

or:

```
export abstract class ChildAdapter extends Adapter{

  protected constructor() {
    super(ChildAdapter.index);
  }

  static index = async () {...}
```

And for future readers, the reason Eslint gives this warning is discussed [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unbound-method/).